# Why is my unit not able to pick up power in Blitz?

Tags: halo-wars-2

In Blitz, you play unit cards to spawn units, which requires power.  To get more power, you can collect it by destroying caches of it around the map and picking it up.

I spawned a unit (in this case, a Jackrabbit) next to one of these caches where it then aided in destroying it (I had a Scorpion tank farther away also damaging the cache).  But it wasn't able to pick up the power with my Jackrabbit for some time.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you spawn a unit outside of your bases bubble, it spawns with something called "Battle Fatigue."

The unit will start with half of its health until the fatigue wears off (or if it is damaged while fatigued, it won't get any health back), and apparently won't be able to pick up power as well. Once the fatigued wore off, I was able to pick up the power.

Comment: If you think that your answer has answered the question, please mark the question as such.

Comment: @ghostwalker13 It's my own answer, you must wait 2 days before you can do so.  I'm full aware on how the site works.

Comment: If you know the answer already why are you asking and immediately answering? Just trying to document questions about the game since its new? (Just curious)

Comment: @n_palum there is nothing wrong with asking and immediately answering your own question. Basically for the reason as you said, plus to help out anyone else who is wondering the same thing. See [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/asking-a-question-to-which-you-already-know-the-answer).

Comment: @TimmyJim I was mostly curious, that's good to know - thanks for the link too